# Can't update Datatables.net cell from DOM sourced table?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables.net with DOM sourced data (the table is initially built using ASP.NET iterators from a data model).

The page runs some AJAX to query the state of the items in the table and I'd like to update them.  Here is my code, but for some reason the call to cell.data("new data") isn't taking.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `cells()` method to find your cell, then attempting to call `cells().data()` on it to set the data. But `cells().data()` does not have a set form.

From the datatables [reference page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells().data()):

> Note that unlike its singular counter part (cell().data()) this method does not have a 'set' form. It can only be used to retrieve data.

Try it by changing your second line to use just `cell()`:

```
var cell = table.cell('[data-courseid=1]');
```

Comment: So embarrassing...  I looked at that code for 3 hours... Thanks!

Comment: Haha no worries, that's a pretty easy mistake to make to be honest